# Configuring network adapter settings from web server CGI

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have an embedded application on an Olinuxino-Maxi board running Arch Linux ARM.

Lighttpd is being used to configure the application. The main application, and the associated CGI file that's accessed via Lighttpd, are written in C.

One small task I have remaining is to be able to set the board's wired Ethernet adapter's own IP, gateway, and DNS information though some input fields on the CGI page.

How could I achieve this?

The way I currently configure the network adapter from boot is to use `netctl` combined with a configuration file that resides in `/etc/netctl`. One method of doing what I want to do could be to have the CGI routines modify that configuration file and then trigger a reboot, though that seems a little hacky. Another way could be to have my main C application configure the network adapter, instead of having `netctl` perform the configuration from boot.